# XCode 10.1 - Notarise macOS App, Ad Hoc, SandBox Off

Tags: xcode, macos, validation

In January 2020, using Xcode 10.1 I have been able to notarise my macOS app and distribute it to my users (not on the App Store). That worked. The users confirmed that when launching the app, it didn't longer show the dialog with the warning message.

**January 2020, to notarise the app**

a) On the Apple Developer web site I used a "Developer ID Application" macOS certificate.

b) On the Apple Developer web site I have added an Identifier with the bundleID of my app.

c) On the iTunes Connect I didn't create any app.

d) I didn't turn the SandBox on.

**Apr 2020, I can't notarise my app anymore**

a) On the Apple Developer web site I used the old  "Developer ID Application" macOS certificate.

b) On the Apple Developer web site I used the old Identifier with the bundleID of my app.

c) On the iTunes Connect now I'm required to create an app. If I don't do that, I get an error message saying that no record found for that app.

d) I have to turn the SandBox on. And, even if I turn it on, Xcode still tells me that I have to turn the SandBox on in the entitlement file (while it is already on). I Quit Xcode, relaunch, but the trouble is still there.

Anyway, I really need to turn the SandBox OFF. So I ask:

**To notarise a macOS app for "Ad Hoc" distribution (not Mac App Store) is it mandatory to turn the SandBox on? Or am I missing something?**